# Putting a mat-icon right in the center of a div with flex?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

Attempting to put a Angular `mat-icon` right in the center of the containing `div` :

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;
            display: flex; 
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100px;
            height: 120px; 
            align-items:center; 
            justify-content: center; ">
    <mat-icon style="font-size: 60px;">
    account_circle
    </mat-icon>
</div>
```

It does not get centered.  [This is the stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-centering).

I noticed that when when showing the outline of the `mat-icon` with developer tooling, it shows that the actual dimensions of the element are right in the middle, but the content of that element are overflowing its boundaries so the icon appears off center.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I think that is becuase of `font-size: 60px;`

Comment: Try this logic:http://jsfiddle.net/xdYUs/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set height and width property to mat-icon.It will work

```
   <mat-icon style="font-size: 60px;height:60px;width:60px;">
    account_circle
    </mat-icon>
```

By default the height and width of the mat-icon is 24px;
[image]

Try this code:

```
<div style="background-color:yellow;
            display: flex; 
            width: 100px;
            height: 120px; 
            align-items:center; 
            justify-content: center; ">
    <mat-icon style="font-size: 60px;height:60px;width:60px;">
    account_circle
    </mat-icon>
</div>
```